# Types 'cv::Mat' and 'int' are not compatible when create a Mat from array

Tags: c++, opencv

In the [documentation on `Mat`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) it shows how to create a `Mat` with a comma-separated initializer as follows:

```
// create 3x3 double-precision identity matrix
Mat M = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

But when I try, it shows an error:

```
Types 'cv::Mat' and 'int' are not compatible
```

how to fix the exception?

thank you

Comment: ***create the Mat in the document***... what document are you talking about?

Comment: humm what version of opencv are you using? and what compiler?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ: The documentation for `Mat`. I edited the OP to link to the documentation file it comes from. OP: The error itself says that you shouldn't be initializing a double matrix with ints, but I don't know why that matters. You can try adding a `.` or a `.0` after the integers so that they're double format, but I don't know why it's not converting implicitly or if it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with your code

```
cv::Mat M = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,3) << 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

I can confirm that it works with gcc 5.4.0 and OpenCV 3.1.0. Small matrices of fixed size should be created with Matx:

```
typedef cv::Matx<double, 3, 3> Mat33d;
Mat33d m(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```